# How to create a shadow in HTML, CSS & JS that doesn't accept clicks, but let it hit behind that layer?

Tags: html, css, shadows

How to create a shadow in HTML, CSS & JS that doesn't accept clicks, but let it hit behind that layer?

I have a some windows in my JS+HTML application. As every window has drop shadows, when somebody clicks near the window and hits the drop shadow layer, I would like to hit the other window that is behind.

I use jQuery*

How to do it? thanks

Comment: Are you using the css box-shadow attribute? What do you mean by _layer_?

Comment: currently im using css box-shadow attribute but I would like to use png. as the PNGs lay on another layer that has some offset to stay in the correct position

Comment: is not cross browser and is not available in older versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/